# Scala Database Mapping Library Similar to iBATIS

Tags: database, scala, ibatis, data-mapping

I've been using iBATIS for years and have been very happy with it. iBATIS is very good about letting one write their own SQL while handling the mundane work of mapping data to/from the objects/database. I would love a Scala specific library that does the same type of mappings that iBATIS does. I figure a Scala specific tool would

- not require the objects to be Java Beans (i.e. getters and setters)
- use Option instead of null values
- I think that's it, but there may be more

I've seen a bunch of stuff on the web talking about ORMs for Java and Scala, but I haven't seen anything like iBATIS for Scala.

Does anybody know of a tool like this in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Scala website (www.scala-lang.org/node/6539), nilskp recommends orbroker (http://code.google.com/p/orbroker/) because it is written natively for Scala.

Answer (score 6):

Times have changed. There is now a MyBatis Scala project which is much more idiomatic to Scala.

http://mybatis.github.io/scala/

I've evaluated it, and it looked like a lot less hassle than any of the other ORM or Scala oriented persistence libraries.

The links on their project page are currently broken, but you can get to the GitHub page here:
https://github.com/mybatis/scala

They have various samples under "mybatis-scala-samples".  This DAO / CRUD example is a particularly nice example: [ItemDAO.scala](https://github.com/mybatis/scala/blob/master/mybatis-scala-samples/src/main/scala/org/mybatis/scala/samples/crud/ItemDAO.scala)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just **carry on using iBatis**? It's Java, after all (and hence can be used from Scala). I still use Spring JDBC as my DAO layer.

As for the scala-specifics; you could add the `@BeanProperty` annotation to generate getters/setters and then declare a method to guard for `null`:

```
@BeanProperty var injectedXyz : String

def xyz : Option[String] = Option(injectedXyz)
```

Admittedly this is not great (i.e. requires extra boilerplate). But I have not seen anything that looks like a widely-used scala DAO layer (for SQL)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this is what I'm trying to avoid. I'm looking for a framework that *leverages* Scala.

Comment: Just to support @oxbow_lakes point of view. I am using iBatis in Scala app and quite happy with it.

Comment: What I want from a DAO layer is trustworthiness. Usually the layer where you interface with your datasource can be isolated from the rest of your application, so I'd be very tempted to take *that* route. You'll have a couple of messy-looking classes but you won't get any nasty surprises

Answer (score 1):

If I were to choose an ORM I'd look into Squeryl (http://squeryl.org/). I've tried out the Lift Mapper and it works well with the Lift Webkit, but it's a little bit to integrated and have certain design choices I don't like.

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer ScalikeJDBC. Take a look at it.

https://github.com/seratch/scalikejdbc

It also has source code generator. Especially if you access the existing legacy database, it's much convenient.

https://github.com/seratch/scalikejdbc-mapper-generator

Comment: Unfortunately documentation is quite outdated for `scalikejdbc` which makes it hard to start using it quickly.